# G++ ARM cross compiling: undefined references

Tags: c++, gcc, arm, cross-compiling

I am trying to compile the [Jasmine OpenSSD](http://www.openssd-project.org) code with arm-none-eabi-g++.
However, it first failed with the following error message

```
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.8.2/../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++
```

To fix that, I ensured that linking with libstdc++.a was possible. Once I fixed that, it failed with the following errors:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.8.2//libgcc.a(unwind-arm.o): In function `get_eit_entry':
/build/buildd/gcc-arm-none-eabi-6/build/arm-none-eabi/libgcc/../../../gcc-4.8.2/libgcc/unwind-arm-common.inc:221: undefined reference to `__exidx_end'
/build/buildd/gcc-arm-none-eabi-6/build/arm-none-eabi/libgcc/../../../gcc-4.8.2/libgcc/unwind-arm-common.inc:221: undefined reference to `__exidx_start'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.8.2/../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/libc.a(lib_a-abort.o): In function `abort':
/build/buildd/newlib-2.1.0/build/arm-none-eabi/newlib/libc/stdlib/../../../../../newlib/libc/stdlib/abort.c:63: undefined reference to `_exit'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.8.2/../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/libc.a(lib_a-signalr.o): In function `_kill_r':
/build/buildd/newlib-2.1.0/build/arm-none-eabi/newlib/libc/reent/../../../../../newlib/libc/reent/signalr.c:61: undefined reference to `_kill'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.8.2/../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/libc.a(lib_a-signalr.o): In function `_getpid_r':
/build/buildd/newlib-2.1.0/build/arm-none-eabi/newlib/libc/reent/../../../../../newlib/libc/reent/signalr.c:96: undefined reference to `_getpid'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.8.2/../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/libc.a(lib_a-sbrkr.o): In function `_sbrk_r':
/build/buildd/newlib-2.1.0/build/arm-none-eabi/newlib/libc/reent/../../../../../newlib/libc/reent/sbrkr.c:58: undefined reference to `_sbrk'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [firmware.elf] Error 1
```

Here is the actual step at which it fails:

```
arm-none-eabi-g++ -static -nostartfiles -ffreestanding -T ld_script -Wl,-O1,-Map=list.txt  ftl.o sata_identify.o sata_cmd.o sata_isr.o sata_main.o sata_table.o initialize.o mem_util.o flash.o flash_wrapper.o misc.o uart.o init.o -o firmware.elf -L"/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.8.2/" -lgcc
```

Can someone suggest a fix? Also, this works perfectly well if I use arm-none-eabi-gcc instead of arm-none-eabi-g++

Comment: A rough guess `-fno-exceptions`?

Comment: Thanks @MatsPetersson! That did supress those errors! Thanks a lot. What does `-fno-exceptions` do? I couldn't find anything online.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is caused by exception handling code that is produced by the compiler, which relies on runtime components - those are not present in your build.

[`-fno-exceptions`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html) turns off exception handling in the code-generation of the compiler.

Comment: Thanks Mats! Also, will this have any run-time side-effects? I plan to run the code on an ARM7TDMI controller.

Comment: Don't try to throw exceptions - something bad will happen, I'm not really sure what (but hopefully all the code is compiled with this flag, and I'm pretty sure it gives an error if you try)